# Kubernetes ingress nginx grafana dashboard prometheus data was empty

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, prometheus, nginx-ingress

I just completely setup prometheus and grafana dashboard using this tutorial https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/monitoring/.

I try to query something in prometheus and it was successfully plotting the graph. But when I access my Grafana dashboard with connecting to prometheus data, it returns empty charts like the below pic.

[image: Grafana Result]

Do I miss something in the step?

Comment: do you see the data getting populated in promethues database?

Comment: How to check it? Exec -it to the container?

Comment: can you check prometheus url in browser

Comment: Yes, it works fine.

Comment: does your grafana display other metrics (not ngnix)?

Comment: I just try nginx-ingress dashboard only, should I try another dashboard template?

Comment: Same issue with me, all nginx-ingress metrics are available in prometheus. Grafana displays all other metrics expect nginx ingress controller. Could you please help ?? @evgenyl

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you didn't create datasource in Grafana before the dashboard import. It is not specified in the manual, but dashboard will not work correctly without it.

How to create Data Source in Grafana:

1. Open Configuration(gear) -> Data Sources
2. Press "Add data source"
3. Select Prometheus
4. Specify Prometheus server URL: (e.g: http://10.22.0.3:32150/)
5. Press "Save & Test"
6. See the confirmation about passed test.

Now, select existing Data Source from the drop-down list during the import of the Nginx Ingress Dashboard from [JSON](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/grafana/dashboards/nginx.json). URL to the dashboard didn't work for me, so I've just copypasted the whole JSON content except two first lines with comments.

For existing dashboard you can change the data source:

1. Open Dashboards -> Manage
2. Click on "Nginx Ingress Controller"
3. Open its settings (gear picture on the top)
4. Select "JSON Model"
5. Update all lines with "datasource": "old_data_source_name", to the desired name
6. Press "Save changes"
7. Press green "Save" button on the left, under "Settings"

Alternatively, you can edit every element on the dashboard and select the desired data source from the drop-down list. Not very convenient way, so I'd prefer to import dashboard again.

Comment: I did it already, but still empty. I have also exposed the metrics.

Comment: Could you try to edit CPU usage graph and check if there is a correct data source selected? Is it possible that you are looking on the old dashboard after importing a new one?

Comment: Sure, let me try first.

Comment: @JustinusHermawan have you ever resolved this issue?

Comment: @dvdblk haven't yet.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the annotation is applied to the **metrics service** object: `prometheus.io/scrape: "true"`.

I was having the same problem as you and this solved it for me. I am using helm to deploy my nginx-ingress. I have the following settings that made this work:

`.controller.metrics.enabled: true`

`.controller.metrics.serviceMonitor.enabled: true`

`.controller.metrics.service.annotations.prometheus.io/scrape: true`

Comment: Hi! I have just the same problem, but I'm also pretty new to Helm and Grafana ecosystem. Could you please tell, maybe add some screenshots, how to perform all the required steps to setup NginX Ingress dashboard in Grafana?